# WASAPI in sharemode error AUDCLNT_E_CPUUSAGE_EXCEEDED

Tags: c++

this is an example of code similar to my previous one and with this, after instantiating 40 threads the error message AUDCLNT_E_CPUUSAGE_EXCEEDED appears.
I am using it to simulate a piano and while playing there can be more than 40 sounds running at the same time so, 40 threads is not enough.
From computer resources, however, this does not appear to be so, the CPU usage of my process remains <2%.
Microsoft says to intervene using MMCSS on thread priority but I haven't solved that either.

Thanks

```
void PlayBuf(short *fileBytes, int fileSize)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    IMMDeviceEnumerator *deviceEnumerator = NULL;
    IMMDevice* audioDevice;
    IAudioClient2* audioClient;
    WAVEFORMATEX wfx = {};
    IAudioRenderClient* audioRenderClient;
    UINT32 bufferSizeInFrames;
    UINT32 bufferPadding;
    int16_t* buffer;
    
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator),NULL,CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator),(LPVOID *)(&deviceEnumerator));
    assert (hr == S_OK);

    hr = deviceEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender,eConsole,&audioDevice);
    assert(hr == S_OK);
    deviceEnumerator->Release();

    hr = audioDevice->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioClient2),CLSCTX_ALL,NULL,(LPVOID*)(&audioClient));
    assert(hr == S_OK);
    audioDevice->Release();

    wfx.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
    wfx.nChannels = 2;
    wfx.nSamplesPerSec = 44100;
    wfx.wBitsPerSample = 16;
    wfx.nBlockAlign = (wfx.nChannels * wfx.wBitsPerSample) / 8;
    wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec = wfx.nSamplesPerSec * wfx.nBlockAlign;

    const int64_t REFTIMES_PER_SEC = 10000000;
    REFERENCE_TIME requestedSoundBufferDuration = REFTIMES_PER_SEC * DurataSuono;
    DWORD initStreamFlags = ( AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_RATEADJUST);

    hr = audioClient->Initialize(AUDCLNT_E_CPUUSAGE_EXCEEDED,initStreamFlags,requestedSoundBufferDuration,0, &wfx, NULL);
    assert(hr == S_OK);

    hr = audioClient->GetService(__uuidof(IAudioRenderClient),
    (LPVOID*)(&audioRenderClient));
    assert(hr == S_OK);

    hr = audioClient->GetBufferSize(&bufferSizeInFrames);
    assert(hr == S_OK);


    audioClient->Reset();
    hr = audioClient->Start();
    assert(hr == S_OK);

    hr = audioRenderClient->GetBuffer(fileSize, (BYTE**)(&buffer));
    assert(hr == S_OK);

    hr = audioRenderClient->ReleaseBuffer(fileSize, 0);
    assert(hr == S_OK);

    Sleep(2000);

    audioClient->Stop();
    audioClient->Release();
    audioRenderClient->Release();
}
```

Comment: I found the solution, thanks anyway

Comment: it is not clear to me how wasapi is handled in SHARE mode

Comment: sorry, solved myself

Comment: Could you share how you resolved it? It'll help others having the same issue.